# How do I boot from a different disk?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, debian, grub

I have a working Debian installation. It boots from `/sda` using GRUB2, with the root partition on `sda1`. Its a standard install, nothing strange.

I've added a 16GB mSATA device which appears as `sdc`. I want to place the kernel and initrd here and boot from it, but keep the root on `sda1`.

Installing GRUB into `sdc` is not an issue. Having it properly find `/boot` appears to be. After booting from this disk I end up in the GRUB rescue shell, with it unable to find `/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod`. This sequence of commands is enough to boot the system:

```
set root=hd2,1
set prefix=(hd2,1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

Running `set` alone indicates that the `root` and `prefix` are still set to `hd0`. I do not know how to set those. The must be stored in the stage1 bootloader somewhere, but I don't see obvious options to any of the GRUB tools to set them.

Ideally, I'd be able to do this with some standard configuration so its safe against GRUB upgrades in the future.

Comment: As to why I'm doing this, the intent is to encrypt `sda` and use a script in the initrd to do a challenge/response sequence with a Yubikey, use those credentials to unlock the decryption key, and then mount the `sda` with LUKS. I've got this bit all sorted out, its just the boot that's causing me problems.

Comment: Has the boot order been set in BIOS?

Comment: Yes. "After booting from this disk..."